# Const correctness in Java using Annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, constants

Is there an existing library that allows me to annotate a Java method as @Const, so that the compiler (using apt I presume) will flag an error if it updates a field, or invokes a non-@Const method on a field; and annotate a parameter as @Const, so that the accepting method cannot invoke any of its non-@Const methods, or update any of its fields?

(Basically, trying to add const-correctness to Java using annotations; there are some obvious details not covered in the question above, such as assigning to/from a @Const-typed parameter, etc.)

I've found this: http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=182158080 but it seems like it's only available as part of IDEA.

Following a request for clarification below, here's sample code to show what I mean:

```
class Person {
  private String name;
  private String address;

  @Const public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  ... etc. for address
}
```

Now, if I define a method such as:

```
void processPerson(@Const Person p)
```

a line such as: `p.getName()` would be OK in `processPerson`, since `getName` was marked as a @Const method. But calling `p.setName()` from within `processPerson` would be flagged as an error.

Note that this is very different from `final`: if the parameter was defined as `final Person p`, any assignment to `p` would have been illegal, but it's still perfectly valid to modify what `p` refers to (either using `p.setName(...)` or even more directly, with `p.name = ...`.

Comment: did you try to use `final` keyword for this purpose? What's wrong with it?

Comment: a final method is a method that cannot be overridden. That's different.

Comment: I mean not final method. I mean final argument. I know what final method is :)

Comment: A final parameter means the method cannot re-assign the reference; but it can still modify the object that the parameter refers to. Which is (a) not what I'm looking for, and (b) utterly useless (at least in my view).

Comment: @M, it is not utterly useless, but perhaps it would be easier to see what you THEN mean if you wrote up some sample code?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You really can modify the object internally. I personally use frameworkless solution for such tasks: If it is collection I wrap it using `Collection.unmodifireableList()` etc., if it my own class I either implement logic that does not allow modifications in class itself or, better, wrap the object using aspect. The aspect may be implemented either using one of aspect frameworks (like AspectJ) or using dynamic proxy. I understand your wishes to have framework that does this automatically and wish you good luck to find one.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Sample code added to the question.

Comment: @AlexR: Sure, using immutable objects is a great solution, but not always applicable. And `unmodifiableList()` has a runtime price. What I'm looking for is a pure compile-time solution.

Comment: @M. Elkstein: I think *"OO over immutable objects"* might be something you could be interested in (but, granted, it requires a shift away from Java idiosynchrasies, like beans and setters ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [JSR-305](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305) supposedly does just about what you're looking for
- Personally, I'd see if I can use [Hibernate Validator - Bean Validation (JSR-303)](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) for that. It's a wonderful little lib (doesn't depend on hibernate, it's small) and it does wonders to keeping your data clean. See the [documentation](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator/docs).
- A google guy also started [Contracts for Java](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2011/02/contracts-for-java.html) recently, but it might not be production quality yet.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#igj-checker), which basically has checkers that try to detect software defects [JSR-305] via an extensible type annotation system [JSR-308].

It has an immutability checker (2 actually) which allows you to annotate code with immutability annotations like @Mutable, @Immutable, and @Readonly.  This tool differentiates between an immutable instance and a read-only reference.

I *love* this framework and mainly use it for null checking, but I am trying to start using the immutability checker and interning checker more.

> annotate a parameter as @Const, so that the accepting method cannot invoke any of its non-@Const methods, or update any of its fields?

Would look like:

```
void addFriend(@ReadOnly Friend friend) { this.friends.add(friend); }
```

> allows me to annotate a Java method as @Const, so that the compiler (using apt I presume) will flag an error if it updates a field, or invokes a non-@Const method on a field; and

It would look like this for the example in the question:

```
public String getName(@ReadOnly Person this) {
  return name;
}
```

The `@ReadOnly` here indicates the receiver (the `this` instance whose method is being called) should *NOT* be modified. Despite the apparent extra parameter, the method is still called as usual:

```
@ReadOnly Person person = new Person();
person.getName();
```

---

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! Been looking for something like this for ages, so happy to finally have it with Java 8. Very powerful stuff, with an Eclipse plugin and with Maven, Ant, Gradle, etc. plugins too, for anyone else interested.

Just one recommendation is that the IGJ Annotations look much more expressive than the Javari checker for anyone confused by the feature overlap. Javari should probably be ignored imho.

(Also - edited answer to correct receiver annotation on methods.)

Answer (score 0):

I am seconding @AlexR comment, this can be done using AspectJ, something along these lines:

```
public aspect ConstAspect{
declare warning : withincode(* *(..,@Const (*),.. ) ) : "Calling Const Method..";
}
```

This is not correct for your requirements, but I basically want to show an approach, In the above case any method which has a @Const on a parameter is tagged with a warning. With a better joinpoint, all the points of concern can be tagged with an error.

Answer (score -7):

`const` was in C++. Java apparently ditched it on purpose. And now people growing up without really experienced `const` think it's a good idea.

Once you marked one method as `const`, it'll spread like cancer, pretty soon you'll find yourself `const` almost everything. It would have been better to have a `not-const`.

Utterly it's useless. It's only appealing academically, doesn't help anybody in real programmnig.

Comment: It's very, very arguable. I used `const` a lot in my C++ programs, and I don't remember it spreading. Marking getters as const and making const overloads of access operators (like `operator[]`) really helps to prevent accidental modifications to objects.

Comment: I think const is good too (8 years of C++ experience). And about spreading - how about the exception specification on a method? It does spread like cancer, but Java devs manage to live with it.

Comment: It's a *good* thing that const spreads 'like cancer'. The more stuff that's const correct the safer your code from abuse.

Comment: @EliasVasylenko I can see why it's irritating from a coding standpoint, since it makes signatures look rather long. I'd argue that method parameters should always be treated as `const` unless explicitly marked otherwise as `mutable`. Then you could make your code look _less_ verbose by improving the design :).

Comment: @Navneeth Absolutely! I completely agree with that. In the context of the question though, I think there is a tension between wanting to choose a sensible default and wanting our hypothetical annotation-processor to be opt-in rather than opt-out. I personally would avoid a system which changed the semantics of my code only in the *absence* of a special annotation. For a non-Java language yeah, I think having a keyword for mutability would be a better choice. That and have fields be private and final by default, etc...